# HTTP Authentication with PHP's Zend XML RPC Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc, http-authentication, zend-xmlrpc

I am using the Zend library's XML RPC Client in a PHP application to pull data from another server over XML RPC. However the other server is using HTTP basic authentication. How can I tell the XMLRPC client to use authentication for the requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Zend_XmlRpc_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html) internally uses a [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) which handles the basic HTTP communication. You can retrieve the HTTP client with:

```
$httpClient = $rpcClient->getHttpClient();
```

and then you can set the requires authentication parameters:

```
$httpClient->setAuth($username, $password, Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC);
```